# How to procedurally generate pixel art from pre draw assets?

Tags: python, pixel, procedural

I want to design a load of pixel art crabs (crabs are just an example) in different colours with different backgrounds, claws, gloves, eyes etc.
The way I envision it is that I would draw multiple assets that a program will stick together randomly and check if it’s the same as another it’s already generated. I assume it would be put together via a grid (one section of the grid will always be a claw but it will a randomly selected by the program for example. All the other sections of the grid will be for one specific part of the body as well).

I have no idea how to do this or where to start. I’m quite new to coding so I’m really looking for advice. How can I achieve this? What are some good key words to search for tutorials that might help? What libraries or anything will I need to use to have my code create the pictures? How do I link the drawn assets to the code? How do I get the code to export the generated designs to a folder? And anything else you know I’ve missed!

The pixel art will just end up being art, not game assets or anything.

Thanks a lot for reading and also thanks a lot for any help! Much appreciated! I know this is very noob stuff and I’m more than willing to put in the work, I just need some guidance from you guys!

Comment: Good question, though probably off-topic. The book "Generative design: visualize, program, and create with processing" is a good way to start. The book has two versions, one which targets the original Java-based version of Processing and one which targets the newer JavaScript-based library p5.js.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you would write code to read from the original images, them paste them together into new images.

- The processing programming language is a great tool when coding for artistic purposes: https://processing.org/
- You may take a look at this list of articles and tools for creative coding: https://github.com/terkelg/awesome-creative-coding